# Problems compiling libjingle/gtk+-2.0 for Mac OS X

Tags: macos, gtk, pkg-config, libjingle

I'm trying to compile libjingle on Mac OSX Snow Leopard. The INSTALL file said to './configure', 'make' and 'make install', as usual. But make fails for me. Initially it gave some messages indicating that I didn't have pkg-config installed (I guess OSX doesn't come with it installed?), so I downloaded pkg-config from http://pkgconfig.freedesktop.org/releases/

Now I get this message:

```
Package gtk+-2.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `gtk+-2.0.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'gtk+-2.0' found
```

I tried to install gtk by using the script at SourceForge: http://sourceforge.net/projects/gtk-osx/

(this is the website pointed to by the gtk website)

Running the script didn't really seem to do anything, here is the output:

```
$./gtk-osx-build-setup.sh
Checking out jhbuild (2.27.3) from git...
From git://git.gnome.org/jhbuild
 * tag               2.27.3     -> FETCH_HEAD
Installing jhbuild...
Installing jhbuild configuration...
Installing gtk-osx moduleset files...
Done.
$
```

And I still get that error message about "Package gtk+-2.0 not found" while make-ing libjingle. Help will be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT**

I've since come to the conclusion that MacPorts isn't the best way to install GTK anymore; the [official OSX port of GTK](https://live.gnome.org/GTK%2B/OSX/Building) is better. What your original problem probably was is that you weren't compiling your program from within the jhbuild environment; use

```
jhbuild shell
```

to start up an environment.

**Original answer**

The best way to compile GTK programs on OS X is to install [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org) and then use that to install GTK by typing:

```
sudo port install gtk2
```

in a Terminal. Install any other packages you end up needing in the same fashion. When all that's done, set your path as follows:

```
export PATH=/opt/local:$PATH
```

and you should be able to compile your program.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind with MacPorts and OSX is that by default it compiles everything for X11 which is probably not what you want.  I had to do this:

  sudo port install gtk2 +no_x11 +quartz +universal

The +universal part was needed for Snow Leopard which is 64-bit by default.

Answer (score 3):

I have solved same error using this export:

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH
```

Maybe this can help someone...